# jQuery attr title issue

Tags: jquery

I'm not able to change the title attribute of div dynamically.
Here is my code :

**EDIT:**

```
<div id='DivId'></div>
```

this div is dialog div. 
On click of button 'First' & 'Second', Dialog will open

```
// On click of button First:
$('#DivId').removeAttr('title');
$('#DivId').attr('title','first');

// On click of button Second:
$('#DivId').removeAttr('title');
$('#DivId').attr('title','second');
```

On the first button click, `title` remains that only, however, on clicking of second button, the title does not change.

**EDIT**

if I remove `$('#DivId').removeAttr('title');` then also it is not working.

Comment: You don't have to remove the attribute to set it to something else ?

Comment: with out removeAttr also it is not working

Comment: Show us more code, how do you do this on click ?

Comment: how do you bind the click event handlers to the buttons?

Comment: @PoonamBhatt, your syntax is correct but can you please let us know that the particular code executed during the onload event ?

Comment: Nope, the syntax is not correct, why would you remove the title attribute just to set it on the next line ?

Comment: @PoonamBhatt Can you show us the HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know but `$('#Divid').attr('title', 'first');` is not working for me...so I tried to remove `$('#Divid').removeAttr('title');` first , then apply new title. But did not worked. so I made 2 Div instead of one, and give title accordingly

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be enough :

```
// On click of button First:
$('#DivId').attr('title','first');

// On click of button Second:
$('#DivId').attr('title','second');
```

... you don't need to use `removeAttr` since the attribute `title` will be overridden by the new setting.

**EDIT** : See **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eywk/)** ... not need to use `removeAttr`

Comment: Did you see the comment? `with out removeAttr also it is not working – Poonam Bhatt 10 mins ago`

Comment: @PraveenKumar : it's difficult to see comments while you write an answer. You could point it out (no need to down vote) so I can edit my answer or add a fiddle to support it.

Comment: Removed it. Just to let you know. What were you doing for the 8 minutes? Didn't see it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar : scrolling down the page ;)

Answer (score 0):

you have to do that this way: **[http://jsfiddle.net/haeze/](http://jsfiddle.net/jjMQW/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn1', function() {
    $('#Divid').removeAttr('title');
    $('#Divid').attr('title', 'first');
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn2', function() {
    $('#Divid').removeAttr('title');
    $('#Divid').attr('title', 'second');
});
```